# Create controller file in separate folder using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need to keep my controller page in separate folder.But it is showing me the below error.

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/ng/areq?p0=homecontroller&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
```

I am explaining my code below.

> app.js:

```
var GoFastoApp=angular.module('GofastoHome',['ngRoute']);
GoFastoApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl : 'view/home.html',
        controller  : 'homecontroller'
    })
    .when('/deptinfo',{
        templateUrl : 'view/info.html',
        controller  : 'infocontroller'
    })
    .when('/TimeTable',{
        templateUrl : 'view/time.html',
        controller  : 'timecontroller'
    })
    .when('/course',{
        templateUrl : 'view/course.html',
        controller  : 'coursecontroller'
    })
    .when('/subject',{
        templateUrl : 'view/subject.html',
        controller  : 'subjectcontroller'
    })
    .when('/hod',{
        templateUrl : 'view/hod.html',
        controller  : 'hodcontroller'
    })
    .when('/faculty',{
        templateUrl : 'view/faculty.html',
        controller  : 'facultycontroller'
    })
})
```

In the above code i have declared different controller for different template.All the partial template will add into below index page.

> index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="GofastoHome">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>...:::WELCOME TO Channabasavashwara Institude of Technology:::...</title>

    <!-- PACE LOAD BAR PLUGIN - This creates the subtle load bar effect at the top of the page. -->
    <script src="js/angularjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angularroute.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="controller/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- GLOBAL STYLES - Include these on every page. -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/style22.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"  style="margin-top:50px">
      <div class="container" style="width:1270px;">
        <div class="navbar-header navbar-brand">
        Computer Science & Engineering
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Dept. info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Time Table</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Edit <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/course">Course</a></li>
                <li><a href="/subject">Subject</a></li>
                <li><a href="/hod">HOD</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="/faculty">Faculty</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
       <!--main_heading_div-->
        <!--middle_content_details_data-->
        <div class="row" style="padding-top:90px;"  ng-view>


        </div>
        <!--end_middle_content_details_data-->

    </div>
    <!-- /.page-content -->

</div>
</div>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="controller/HomeController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Here i need suppose for `home.html` partial template i will create new homecontroller file in separate folder  and include this file in master page.Here i created one file(`i.e-HomeController.js`) which is given below.

> HomeController.js:

```
var homeapp=angular.module('GofastoHome',[]);
homeapp.controller('homecontroller',function($scope){

})
```

When i include this file i did not get any partial template and when i removed this file link from master page(`i.e-index.html`) the above error is coming.Please help me to resolve this issue. I am using angular.js version 1.4.6.

Comment: I don't really understand the question... Of course you need to include all files needed in the index.html...

Comment: Can yo create plunker for your question? I think problem is with your way to initialize AngularJs module and include all files.

Comment: @Gustav : But after including no partial template is coming.Here my requirement is i will keep all controller file in one folder and will execute respective template.

Comment: @LaxmiSalunkhe : Can you edit your answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a reference to an existing module you must not declare a dependency list!
Remove the brackets and it should work.

```
var homeapp=angular.module('GofastoHome');
```

Answer (score 0):

Always include Angular Plugin file first, then include application **app.js**, configuration files if any and at the end include all angular modules dependencies created like services, directives, factories and at last controllers.

> app.js

```js
// Angular Module initialization
var goFastoApp=angular.module('GofastoHome',['ngRoute']);

// Config Block
GoFastoApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl : 'view/home.html',
        controller  : 'homecontroller'
    })
});
```

> home.controller.js

// Consider this code you have added in separate file for controller

```
goFastoApp.controller('homecontroller',function($scope){
   $scope.username = "Satya";
})
```

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="GofastoHome">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>...:::WELCOME TO Channabasavashwara Institude of Technology:::...</title>

    <!-- PACE LOAD BAR PLUGIN - This creates the subtle load bar effect at the top of the page. -->

    <!-- GLOBAL STYLES - Include these on every page. -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style22.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Page Content -->

    <!-- Plugin Files -->
    <script src="js/angularjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angularroute.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>
    <!-- End Plugin Files -->

    <!-- JS Files -->
    <script src="controller/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="controller/HomeController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- End JS Files -->
</body>
</html>
```